# Centralizing documentation for software

Tags: svn, documentation, versioning, centralized

In our organization we have about 100 software documentations (API, SOAP, technical, ...) saved in SVN repository.

Saving docs in SVN have some benefits, for example versioning. But accessing documentations and searching in them isn't easy, especially for other departments. They have to dig into SVN folder structure.

**It would be better if we could save docs somewhere centralized with versioning and searching feature.**

Below I describe what I expect from versioning and searching.

Searching: Searching simultaneously in all documentations.

Versioning:

1. Sometimes I have two different version of software On production, so I have to have accessible documentation for both versions.
2. We always prepare docs when we work on software but sometimes those apps is deployed on production after several months. So when it goes to production it should be possible to update docs easily, with one click (in SVN we are doing it using merging branch to trunk)

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Do you need full-text search? Or do you want to search by paths only?

Comment: @bahrep   Full text search in contents of documents. Like in Wikipedia